# В чём заключается ошибка в коде?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, null

Пытаюсь передать значение от одной Activity к другой через `putExtra` и принять через `getIntExtra`, но ничего не работает не знаю почему, на входе 2 Activity приходит null

Код первой Activity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)//создание экрана и отрисовка главного активити
            relativeLayout4.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            relativeLayout2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            relativeLayout3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(passiveNavigator)
            val n: String = "60"
            Log.i("----80", n)
            Dannye_Perevod()



fun onClick(view: View) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity_Information::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        var Speed_Dannye = speedCalculationSeekBar?.getProgress()
        var Time_Dannye = timeCalculationSeekBar?.getProgress()
        println("Пришло$Time_Dannye")
        println("Пришло$Speed_Dannye")
        var Dannye_Speed_Perevod = Speed_Dannye?.div(46)
        var Dannye_Time_Perevod = Time_Dannye?.div(1)
        var Dannye_Way_Perevod = Dannye_Speed_Perevod!! * Dannye_Time_Perevod!!
        var Dannye_Speed_String = Dannye_Speed_Perevod.toString()
        var Dannye_Time_String = Dannye_Time_Perevod.toString()
        var Dannye_Way_String = Dannye_Way_Perevod.toString()
        intent.putExtra("Speed", Dannye_Speed_String)
        intent.putExtra("Time", Dannye_Time_String)
        intent.putExtra("Way", Dannye_Way_String)

    }
}
```

Код второй Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__information)
        Priem_Dannye_Vyvod()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun Priem_Dannye_Vyvod() {
        val DannyeSpeed = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Speed_Dannyee)
        val DannyeTime = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.time_Dannye)
        val DannyeWay = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.way_Dannye)
//
        val Time_Priem = intent.getIntExtra("Time", 0)
        val Speed_Priem = intent.getIntExtra("Speed", 0)
        val Way_Priem = intent.getIntExtra("Way", 0)




        println("Пришло$Time_Priem")
        println("Пришло$Speed_Priem")
        println("Пришло$Way_Priem")

    }
```

На махинации с переменными прошу не обращать внимание, это своеобразный костыль

Comment: А где в первой активити putExtra?

Comment: косяк, забыл вставить сюда

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала `putExtra`, и только потом `startActivity` - во вторую активность не передаётся "живой" объект, который можно менять "на лету".
Данные проходят через `Parcel` - аналог сериализации в Андроиде.
Поэтому вторая активность увидит только то, что было в интенте до вызова `startActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Короче, для стабильной работы нужно вставлять отправку между

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity_Information::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Примерно вот так:

```
fun onClick(view: View) {


        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity_Information::class.java)
        var Speed_Dannye = speedCalculationSeekBar?.getProgress()
        var Time_Dannye = timeCalculationSeekBar?.getProgress()
        println("Пришло$Time_Dannye")
        println("Пришло$Speed_Dannye")
        var Dannye_Speed_Perevod = Speed_Dannye?.div(46)
        var Dannye_Time_Perevod = Time_Dannye?.div(1)
        var Dannye_Speed_String = Dannye_Speed_Perevod.toString()
        var Dannye_Time_String = Dannye_Time_Perevod.toString()
        intent.putExtra("Speed", Dannye_Speed_Perevod)
        intent.putExtra("Time", Dannye_Time_Perevod)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

Если вставлять сначала отправку, а потом переход на новою активити, то ничего не получиться.